# Drive to Web forzar limpiar cache automaticamente

Tags: html, css

estoy haciendo una web muy simple para uso particuar utilizando como hosting el almacenamiento de Google Drive.

Para ello estoy utilizando la web "Drive to Web".

La web es muy simple, no es más que un menú con los videos que tengo en mi Drive. El problema es que si hago algún cambio al index.html, dicho cambio no se refleja hasta que refresque la cache del navegador. Mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de obligar al navegador a que no guarde la cache, o a que la refresque cada vez que cargue la web.

Se que puedo configurar mi navegador para ello pero quiero hacerlo desde el archivo, dado que no siempre voy a usar el mismo navegador/dispotivo para acceder.

He probado con unas etiquetas de meta que encontre pero no me funciona, quizás es por el hecho de usar google drive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <title>Una web y videos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <H1>Hello world!</H1>
     <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="Pruebas 1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="Pruebas 2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="Pruebas 3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="Pruebas 4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

PD: Si fuera necesareo utilizar algo de PhP, o javascript no importa

Comment: Hola @ruben generalmente es útil agregar una cola pseudoaleatoria a los paths del tipo `"index.php/?q="+Math.random();` de modo que la dirección sea diferente todas las veces para el navegador y obligue recarga pero sea tratada de la misma manera.